# While loop doesn't stop even after condition is false

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to make a code that generates a password for the user, and I wanted the user to be able to select which types of characters it would like in its password.

When the user decides to not have a certain character, it adds a certain number in an array called `naoColocar`. By default, the array is 0, 0, 0, 0, but if you want to not add lowercase letters it adds 1 to index 0, uppercase letters adds 2 to index 1, numbers add 3 to index 2, special characters add 4 to index 3.

```java
for (int x = 0; x < tamanhoDaSenha; x++) {
            int numAleatorio = random.nextInt(4);
            numAleatorio++;
            
            while (naoColocar[0] == numAleatorio || naoColocar[1] == numAleatorio || naoColocar[2] == numAleatorio || naoColocar[3] == numAleatorio) {
                numAleatorio = random.nextInt(4);
                numAleatorio++;
            }

            switch (numAleatorio) {
                case 1:
                senha += letrasMin[random.nextInt(26)];
                break;

                case 2:
                senha += letrasMai[random.nextInt(26)];
                break;
                
                case 3:
                senha += numeros[random.nextInt(10)];
                break;

                case 4:
                senha += charEspeciais[random.nextInt(11)];
                break;
            }
            }
```

In the code, the for loop chooses a random value from 1 to 4 (`numAleatorio`) and depending on the value, adds a certain character to the password. I made a while loop that checks if the random value is in the array, it would generate a new value to `numAleatorio`, but even when the condition is false, the while loop continues and the password is never generated, why?
Edit: Changed so that now the code generates the correct amount of characters and 9, z and Z are now possible, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: How do you verify that the loop continues when the entire boolean expression is false? What debugging steps have you done and what is the result from these steps?

Comment: BTW The only possible values of `nextInt(3)` are `0`, `1`, and `2` - so "loop chooses a random value from 1 to 4" is not correct

Comment: BTW2 `for (int x = 0; x <= tamanhoDaSenha; x++)` is looping one time more than needed - I would prefer `senha.length() < tamanhoDaSenha` (maybe in a `while`)

Answer (score 1):

You should rely on tests to make sure that the method you wrote works as required, so in this case I wrote some tests based on code you provided.

Please note that this is only example and you should not place model logic in test code and you should test method behaviour.

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource(value = {
        "0,0,0,0", "1,0,0,0", "0,2,0,0", "0,0,3,0", "0,0,0,4", "1,2,0,0", "1,0,3,0", "1,0,0,4",
        "0,2,3,0", "0,2,0,4", "0,0,3,4", "1,2,3,0", "1,2,0,4", "0,2,3,4", "1,0,3,4"}, delimiter = ',')
void shouldNaoColocarDoesNotHaveInfiniteWhileLoop(ArgumentsAccessor aa) {
    int[] naoColocar = {aa.getInteger(0), aa.getInteger(1), aa.getInteger(2), aa.getInteger(3)};
    whileNaoColocar(naoColocar);
}

@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource(value = {"1,2,3,4"}, delimiter = ',')
void shouldNaoColocarHaveInfiniteWhileLoop(ArgumentsAccessor aa) {
    int[] naoColocar = {aa.getInteger(0), aa.getInteger(1), aa.getInteger(2), aa.getInteger(3)};
    assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> whileNaoColocar(naoColocar));
}

void whileNaoColocar(int[] naoColocar) {
    int counter = 0;
    int numAleatorio = random.nextInt(4);
    numAleatorio++;

    while (naoColocar[0] == numAleatorio || naoColocar[1] == numAleatorio ||
            naoColocar[2] == numAleatorio || naoColocar[3] == numAleatorio) {
        numAleatorio = random.nextInt(4);
        numAleatorio++;
        counter++;
        if (counter >= 100) throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

These tests are passing, so that indicates that there is an error in your method logic when dealing with dataset `{1,2,3,4}`

In that case I suggest you to run your code with debugger and see why stop condition does not occur in your while loop.

Comment: but even when naoColocar has none of these values it still doesnt stop